# How to delete 4,600 embedded folders?

Tags: windows, file, batch-file

Trying to get this directory off my computer and can't seem to get it off. Tried creating this bat file to delete them and can't seem to get it correct.

```
:LoopStart
REN "C:\Users\David\Desktop\*" del
MOVE "C:\Users\David\Desktop\del\ "C:\"
RMDIR /S /Q "C:\Users\David\Desktop\del"

GOTO LoopStart
:LoopEnd
```

file path that is continuous is this :

```
C:\Users\David\Desktop\com\example\Lab2-1starter\app\src\main\java
```

Comment: i tried these and it keeps telling me file path is too long or it doesn't delete. Still have 4,579 folders. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. Ill keep looking into it.

Comment: The logic of your script looks wrong to me: you *move* `C:\Users\David\Desktop\del\` do somewhere else, then you try to delete that directory...

Answer (score 1):

Best way to do it easily without any for loops is to use **Robocopy**

first create a empty directory [say C:\empty] This will be your source directory now, now the idea is to overwrite destination directory .

command to delete the entire content of destination directory :

```
robocopy c:\empty c:\yourfolder /purge

/PURGE :: delete dest files/dirs that no longer exist in source
```

Now you can simply run

```
del /s /q c:\yourfolder
```

you can use all above command in a bat file to reuse it in a better way.

This will also delete path with long length , make sure you run from admin command prompt.

Comment: I tried this a couple times today and i stop it after 20 minutes because it just keeps going and going. Gonna let it run all night and see if it works. I will let you know. Thanks again.

Comment: let it run it will work :) , you can observe the same in logs , and visually as well.

Comment: This didn't work, i tried it 3 times. After about 30 minutes it says: robocopy stopped responding.

Comment: I ended up live booting ubuntu from a usb and being able to delete it from there. Thanks for your help.